# A Slack message was sent out during the time when Eventviewer logs show the computer was on sleep mode. Is it possible?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, event-viewer, slack, idle

Could anyone please advise me?
Using my computer, a Slack message was sent out at the time stamped during the time when Event viewer logs show the computer was on sleep mode.  Is it possible?  If it is, how?
The computer was on sleep mode due to System Idle, but while it was sleeping the same computer seems to have been used by a slack member to post a message.

I searched around to find a solution to figure out what was going on with my computer, but could not find a clue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well - *someone* sent the message. Could it have been another computer? Phone?

Comment: Were the contents of the message look like being yours?

Comment: The computer in question was used by one and only one person on November 4th.  This person never used another computer or a phone to use Slack.  On Slack her message was sent out from the computer at 2 pm.  But the Event Viewer shows that the computer was on the sleep mode (on System Idle) from noon to 3 pm.  The "source" was "Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" according to the event viewer.  I am trying to figure out whether the person was indeed using Slack or not at 2 pm.  (I am involved in a court case and it is important for me to figure it out.  Thanks in advance for your help.)